Method and principle of translating an graph from $a \cdot f(mx+n)$ into $b \cdot f(px+q)$
How to translate the graph from $y=\sin(x+2)$ to $y=\sin(2x+2)$?
My classmate has a magical idea: replace $x$ with $2x$ to translate the graph directly. This way, he only needs to halve the image's $x$-width. But it always feels a bit strange.
However, when we solve it by letting $2x+2=2(x+2)-2$ to treat $x+2$ as an independent variable, which means that we need to shift right by $2$ on the basis of reducing its $x$-width, the answer differs.
Universally, suppose that $a$, $b$, $m$, $n$, $p$, $q$ are constants. If we want to translate the graph of $y=a \cdot f(mx+n)$ into $y=b \cdot f(px+q)$, how should we solve it? And what is its principle?
Thank you for your answers.

What do you mean by translate the graph?

I mean convert or transform

If you want to transform a function, it totally depends on what function we are dealing with. Trigonometric functions have their own transformation like $sin(x) = sin (2n\pi + x) $ as $2n\pi $ is it's period

I think OP means that if we have $f(x) = \sin (x+2)$, then how do we write $\sin (2x+2)$ in terms of $f(\cdot)$? That is, for what $u$, in terms of $x$, is $f(u)$ identically equal to $\sin (2x+2)$? Is that right, @Frank?

It appears that my original formulation was not accurate. I meant the translation of the function graph

$y=\sin(2x+2)$ is going to have the same y-value at $x=0$ that $y=\sin(x+2)$ has; however, the periods of oscillation will be half, meaning the graph of $y=\sin(x+2)$ will be compressed horizontally and symmetrically to the $y$-axis (the graph will squeeze into the $y$-axis) until the frequency of waves is double for any given $x$-domain.
In terms of your universal question, as I understand it:
$$y=a \cdot f(mx+n) \rightarrow y=b \cdot f(px+q).$$
Any change from $a \rightarrow b$ will result in a vertical stretch or compression.
A change $m \rightarrow p$ will result in the horizontal stretch or squeeze.
A change $n \rightarrow q$ will result in a shift of the graph horizontally.
This is assuming the vertical axis is the $y$-axis, and the horizontal axis is the $x$-axis.

I think it helps to think in terms of function composition. Define the function $g$ by $g(x)=x+2$ and define the function $h$ by $h(x) = 2x$.
Now $\sin(x+2) = \sin(g(x))$ while $\sin(2x+2) = \sin(g(h(x))$. If we define $f$ by letting $f(x)=\sin(g(x)) = \sin(x+2)$ then $\sin(2x+2) = f(h(x)$. If the graph of $f(x)$ is compared with that of $f(h(x))$, the latter is horizontally compressed by a factor of $\frac{1}{2}$. More precisely, if $(x,y)$ is a point on the graph of $x\mapsto f(x)$, then $\left(\frac{x}{2},y\right)$ is a point on the graph of $x\mapsto f(h(x))$. And this is true of any function $f$, not just our example, as long as $h$ is defined by $h(x)=2x$.
Now let's look at your other proposed method, in which you write $2x+2 = 2(x+2) - 2$. Define the function $k$ by $k(x)=x-2$. Then you have $\sin(2x+2) = \sin(k(h(g(x))))$.
This has to agree with the previous method, and indeed it does. The sine function passes through the origin of the $x$-$y$ plane. In the first method above, the graph first gets shifted left by $2$ units so that this horizontal intercept gets moved to $x=-2$. Then the graph gets compressed horizontally by a factor of $\frac{1}{2}$, so that the intercept ends up at $x=-1$.
In the second method, the sine curve first gets shifted right $2$ units, placing the intercept at $x=2$. Then the graph gets compressed by a factor of $\frac{1}{2}$, moving the intercept to $x=1$. Finally the graph gets shifted left $2$ units, and the intercept ends up at $x=-1$, as before.
To answer your general question, define $g_n$ by $g_n(x)=x+n$ and $h_m$ by $h_m(x)=mx$ for $m\ne0$. Define $F$ by $F(x)=a\cdot f(mx+n)=h_a(f(g_n(h_m(x)))$. To recover $f$ from $F$, we need to apply appropriate inverse functions: $f(x)=h_a^{-1}(F(h_m^{-1}(g_n^{-1}(x))))$. This works since if we replace $F$ with its expression in terms of $f$ we get
$$
h_a^{-1}(h_a(f(g_n(h_m(h_m^{-1}(g_n^{-1}(x))))))),
$$
which reduces to $f(x)$.
Now if $G$ is defined by $G(x) = b\cdot f(px+q) = h_b(f(g_q(h_p(x))))$, we can get $G$ from $F$ by first getting $f$ from $F$ and then getting $F$ from $f$. So
\begin{align}
G(x) &= h_b(h_a^{-1}(F(h_m^{-1}(g_n^{-1}(g_q(h_p(x)))))))\\
&= \frac{b}{a} F\left(\frac{1}{m}(px+q-n)\right).
\end{align}
In terms of transformations of graphs, the graph of $x\mapsto G(X)$ is obtained from the graph of $x\mapsto F(x)$ by the following steps:

scale the vertical by a factor of $\frac{1}{a}$;
scale horizontally by a factor of $m$;
shift right by $n$;
shift left by $q$;
scale horizontally by a factor of $\frac{1}{p}$;
scale the vertical by a factor of $b$.

Some of these transformations commute with each other, so the order of operations is somewhat flexible. For example, the vertical transformations can be done either before or after the horizontal ones. You can try this out on your original example to see that it works, and agrees with your classmate's suggestion.

One approach is to apply the scalar of $~(1/2)~$ to the size of the $~x$-axis units, so that (for example) the point $~(1,0)~$ is re-labeled $~(2,0).$
Then, there is absolutely no change to the graph.
However, at this point, the [x-unit::y-unit] aspect ratio has been changed from [1::1] to [2::1].
In order to restore the aspect ratio to [1::1], you must horizontally stretch, by a factor of $~2,~$ both the $~x$-axis units, and the corresponding graph.
